# NSString problem on iphone while displaying on UILabel

Tags: iphone

i have a issue , i am asking as new question as previoes one was messed

```
NSString *s=@"hi\nhello\n\nwelcome to this world\ni m jhon"
label.frame = ...//big enough height
label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.text = s;
```

**this code helps me to separate string based on \n**

but if i do this

```
NSString *s=Ad.content //where Ad.content value is **hi\nhello\n\nwelcome to this world\ni m jhon**


label.numberOfLines = 0;
label.text = s;
```

**i am not able to sperate them by \n** , what i am doing wrong here  kindly suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"\n" is not a special token handled by UILabel. It is, in fact, a special token handled by the compiler. When the compiler sees "Hello\nWorld", it converts that into the sequence of characters `'H' 'e' 'l' 'l' 'o' LF 'W' 'o' 'r' 'l' 'd'` (where LF is ASCII code 10, or newline). For whatever reason, your `Ad.content` contains literal "\n" sequences instead of newlines. The best solution is to look at where the content of Ad.content comes from and fix it to actually have real newlines instead of "\n" sequences. If you absolutely must have "\n" sequences, then you can use `-[NSMutableString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]`. Of course, if anyone wants to have the literal sequence "\n" show up, then they can't do that. If you want to support generic backslash-escaping (so the literal sequence "\n" would be represented as "\n"), then you can use a more complicated approach with `NSScanner` where you find each "\", pull out the next character, and handle it appropriately.

My recommendation is to fix `Ad.content` to contain actual newlines.

Comment: well explanation thanks a lot  for me stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString: works like charm :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *_stringToSplit = @"hi\nhello\n\nwelcome to this world\ni m jhon";
NSArray *_splitItems = [_stringToSplit componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSMutableArray *_mutableSplitItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[_splitItems count]]; 
[_mutableSplitItems addObjectsFromArray:_splitItems];

[_splitItems count] is your solution
```

cheers Endo

Answer (score 0):

i did this . it was so easy damn i am mad  thanks guys

**NSString *ss  = [aDl.content  stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\n"];**